# RecyclerView Items are getting INVISIBLE in RecyclerView with multiple item types on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For the first time, my Recyclerview is getting loaded as I required, but when I scroll it all my items are getting INVISIBLE , Please find the attached video of the issue I am facing Thanks in Advance , https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A695imvTIYYhUlIqcFL2o4k_UZak7wUu

This is my `fragment_offer.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    tools:context=".views.fragments.OfferFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        tools:context=".views.fragments.OfferFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvOffers"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my OfferAdapter looks like.

```
.
.
.
public class OfferAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Offer> mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private static final int OFFER_TYPE = 1;
    private static final int HEADER_TYPE = 0;

    public OfferAdapter(Context context, List<Offer> list) {
        mList = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(viewType == HEADER_TYPE){
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_sort_search,null);
           viewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(view);
        }
        else if(viewType == OFFER_TYPE){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.trailer_offer_item,null);
            viewHolder = new OfferViewHolder(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(getItemViewType(position) == HEADER_TYPE){
            HeaderViewHolder headerViewHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
            headerViewHolder.imgSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Sort clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            headerViewHolder.rlSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"search clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Offer offer = mList.get(position-1);
            OfferViewHolder offerViewHolder = (OfferViewHolder) holder;
            offerViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(offer.getOfferName());
            offerViewHolder.tvSubTitle.setText(offer.getOfferDescription());
            Utility.loadImage(mContext,offer.getMobileImage(),offerViewHolder.imgOffer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            return HEADER_TYPE;
        }
        else {
            return OFFER_TYPE;
        }
    }

    public void setOffers(RealmResults<Offer> offersList) {

    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private RelativeLayout rlSearch;
        private ImageButton imgSort;
        public HeaderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgSort = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibSort);
            rlSearch = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlSearch);
        }
    }

    public class OfferViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView tvSubTitle;
        private final TextView tvTitle;
        private final ImageView imgOffer;

        public OfferViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOfferTitle);
            tvSubTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOfferSubtitle);
            imgOffer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgOffer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `OfferFragment.java` looks like

```
.
.
.
public class OfferFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private RecyclerView rvOffers;
    private RealmResults<Offer> offers;
    private OfferAdapter offersAdapter;

    public OfferFragment() {

    }

    public static OfferFragment newInstance() {
        OfferFragment fragment = new OfferFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offer, container, false);
        rvOffers = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvOffers);
        setData();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setData() {
        offers = realm.where(Offer.class).findAll();
        offersAdapter = new OfferAdapter(getContext(),offers);
        offers.addChangeListener(offersList -> {
            offersAdapter.setOffers(offersList);
        });
        rvOffers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        rvOffers.setAdapter(offersAdapter);
    }

}
```

this is my trailer_offer_item.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/clParent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgOffer"
            style="@style/ImageViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_view_gradient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOfferSubtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_lsmall"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_lsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xxlsmall"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aktiv_regular"
            android:text="Dolor sit amet 20%"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_lmedium"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOfferTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_lsmall"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_lsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xxlsmall"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aktiv_bold"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvOfferSubtitle">
        </TextView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_sort_search,null);
```

to

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_sort_search,parent, false);
```

similarly for the other view as well. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
 // return the total number of view types. this value should never change at      runtime
 return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
// return a value between 0 and (getViewTypeCount - 1)
return position % 2;
}
```